# Google Play Billing Library - Hot to check consumption status?

Tags: android, android-billing

I am updating an older Android app to the latest Google Play Billing Library.
To handle consumable products the docs say:

> Make sure the purchase wasn't already consumed by checking the
> consumptionState from the result of calling Purchases.products:get

Since it may happen that the app / purchase process is interrupted before a consumable purchase is consumed, I would like to use `queryPurchasesAsync` + `onQueryPurchasesResponse` to query previous purchases and check there consumption state.

Problem: `Purchase` does not has any `consumptionState` property and `Purchase.getProducts()` only delivers a String list of product IDs.

So how / where to get `consumptionState`?

Comment: same problem is happening with me. it gives acknowledged but not giving  consumptionState. if you got the solution till now please share.

Answer (score 0):

I am in the same situation.

It seems that if you try to consume a product already consumed the "billingResult.getResponseCode()" doesn't return OK in "onConsumeResponse" listener.

This looks like a bad workaround but it works ...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).